# Как вычислять в entry в tkinter выражения

Tags: python, tkinter

Как при помощи entry считать выражения вида:
4+5-7*8
И в этом же поле вывести результат

Проблема в том, что тип строковый
Пробовал через split разделять на числа и переводить в float, но таким образом получается только с двумя числами работать

Comment: конечно же, используя split можно работать с больше, чем двумя числами. И конечно же, ты не первый, кто пытается вычислять выражение записанное в строку. Если бы ты воспользовался поиском, то нашел бы тут 100500 вопросов и ответов на эту тему.

Comment: Вопрос-дубликат про консольный калькулятор, но ничего не мешает прикрутить вычисление к текстовому полю.